# Codeigniter: Active Records Insert Unique values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am importing GMail contacts from Google API and just want to persist unique email ids into database.
Is it possible to insert unique records using codeigniter's Active Record? 
Does CodeIgniter provide it out of the box?
If I make the column unique the query throws exception. After digging into documentation I understood that CodeIgniter doesn't provide `try catch` blocks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: try to search the email before insert into database, if existing, skip the new record, if not, insert it.
Or, you can implement a REPLACE method in Active Record, and put a unique index on email field

Answer (score 2):

your email field have to be unique in your table indexes.

```
$query_string = $this->db->insert_string('table', $data);
$query_string = str_replace('INSERT INTO', 'INSERT IGNORE INTO', $query_string);

$req = $this->db->query($query_string);

if($req->affected_rows() == 1) {
   //data inserted
} else {
   //email exists already
}
```

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without
>   IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY
>   value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is
>   aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is
>   issued. Data conversions that would trigger errors abort the statement
>   if IGNORE is not specified. With IGNORE, invalid values are adjusted
>   to the closest values and inserted; warnings are produced but the
>   statement does not abort.

[MySQL INSERT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html?ff=nopfpls)

[CI Database Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

Comment: This seems like a nice solution, but is it bad practice? After all, it is throwing an error...

Comment: Is `IGNORE` keyword is bad practice ? Well, i would say no. If you worry about wrong data that can be in your queries and no error will be throwned. So your problem is when you check these data. You cannot let mysql check them for you. That is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a base model (application/core/MY_Model.php) and implement a save function to insert if new and update if exists. Extend your model from it.

This is an extract from http://thephpcode.com/blog/codeigniter/a-smart-codeigniter-model

```
public function save($data,$tablename="")
{
if($tablename=="")
{
    $tablename = $this->table;
}
$op = 'update';
$keyExists = FALSE;
$fields = $this->db->field_data($tablename);
foreach ($fields as $field)
{
    if($field->primary_key==1)
    {
        $keyExists = TRUE;
        if(isset($data[$field->name]))
        {
            $this->db->where($field->name, $data[$field->name]);
        }
        else
        {
            $op = 'insert';
        }
    }
}

if($keyExists && $op=='update')
{
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->update($tablename);
    if($this->db->affected_rows()==1)
    {
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
}

$this->db->insert($tablename,$data);

return $this->db->affected_rows();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data comes from a from, CI provides a `form_validation` class that can validate your form on the server side.By form_validation has a rule called `is_unique` its checks if the given value is already exist on the database or not. you can see a complete and clear explanation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Or, you can check it manually before inserting your email in that unqiue column.

```
$this->db->select('email');
$this->db->where(array('email'=>$email));
$query = $this->db->get('yourtable');
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    // the query returned data, so the email already exist.
}else{
    // the email not exists, so you can insert it.
}
```